# Can a Facebook app post the same message at the same time on 100K users connected to it?

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth

I am developing a web App for users who want to post the exact same thing on a given time on their own Facebook wall to make a message viral. Of course, considering they granted my app the permission to do so and signed up specifically for that matter. Also, the frequency of such a blast message would be rare, no more than once or twice a week.

I would like to know if anyone has any experience in doing this and what the limitations are since I can't find them on Facebook's developer support.

Answer (score 0):

This type of behavior is discouraged by the Facebook ToS. Further, in order to publish to a user's feed you need to have a current access token for that user. If they are currently connected and using your app, you have access to those tokens and publishing should be possible but very well might get your app banned for ToS violation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am browsing through https://www.facebook.com/terms.php to understand why, if not for commercial use, will it be banned.

Comment: Because it ruins the site experience for users and will be considered spam.

Comment: I can't see how. It would obey the will of those voluntarily subscribed to the app precisely for that matter and their friends would see exactly what their other friends intended. The post will only be seen once, with multiple people backing it but it would still be one single post throughout your timeline.